# selecting an angularjs view and controller at runtime

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

I'm developing a management console for various types of events such as concerts, weddings, meetings, exhibitions, theatre, etc.

This application is being implemented with angular JS as the front end which calls into a back end JSON service.

Here's what I want to achieve

Within an angular JS view/controller I would like to set up a wizard that has three steps...
Step 1: edit a form with the common properties in the model (everything before "eventType" in the json below)
Step 2: Load a custom view and controller depending on the "eventType" property of the model
Step 3: Present a message with the event title and a confirm button to post the model JSON to a back end service

The problem is with step 2 in the process.
I want to basically do something like this...

```
<div id="wizard_step_2" ng-model="$scope.eventData" ng-view="/views/eventtypes/{{$scope.eventType}}Editor.html" ng-controller="{{$scope.eventType}}Controller">
</div>
```

The eventData model differs from item type to item type, and I may need to implement functions on the scope that are specific to the eventType hence the need for a controller.

For the view, I know this can be done with ng-include and registering the controller but I lose the scope in the new controller and view where I need it to manipulate the eventData on the parent scope.

Can this be done or am I barking up the wrong tree?

JSON models

```
{
    "id": 1234,
    "eventTitle": "Some sample title",
    "eventOrganizer": "John Doe",
    "eventDate": "1/1/2015",
    "eventTime": "02:00:00",
    "eventLocation": {
        "AddressLine1": "43 duck st.",
        "AddressLine2": "",
        "TownCity": "Fakesville",
        "Country": "SampleCountry"
    },
    "eventType": "WEDDING",
    "eventData": {
        "BrideName": "Jane Blogs",
        "GroomName": "John Doe",
        "NumberOfGuests": 300,
        "PhotographerName": "Bill Jones",
        "CatererName": "Joes Fine Foods",
    }
}

{
    "id": 1234,
    "eventTitle": "Some sample title",
    "eventOrganizer": "John Doe",
    "eventDate": "1/1/2015",
    "eventTime": "02:00:00",
    "eventLocation": {
        "AddressLine1": "43 duck st.",
        "AddressLine2": "",
        "TownCity": "Fakesville",
        "Country": "SampleCountry"
    },
    "eventType": "CONCERT",
    "eventData": {
        "ArtistName": "Richer Equestrian",
        "SupportingArtist": "Cooper Planet",
        "Agent": "Steve Black",
        "TicketsOnsale": 300,
        "ArtistGenre": "Rock and Roll",
    }
}
```